# Error log shows error about Software caused connection abort

Tags: codenameone

I see the following error in the production log. Please advise what could be causing this error. These email logs are so abstract really not able to determine the issue.

secondly, where is the device information is enclosed here.

```
[Network Thread] 45:4:44,291 - The operation couldn’t be completed. Software caused connection abort
[Network Thread] 45:4:44,297 - Exception: java.io.IOException - The operation couldn’t be completed. Software caused connection abort


 java.io.IOException
at com_codename1_io_ConnectionRequest.performOperation:884
at com_codename1_io_NetworkManager_NetworkThread.run:325
at com_codename1_impl_CodenameOneThread.run:176
at java_lang_Thread.runImpl:153
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a "feature" of iOS 12: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/106838

It seems you're using the connection when the app went to the background. Apple disallows that and historically would randomly kill the app when you did that without a background task.

Comment: i have a location polling where as app will poll the location. How can i make the condition not to poll when the App goes into backgroud. Please suggest an example. Thanks.

Comment: When `stop()` is invoked it means the app is in the background you can use `Display.isMinimized()` to check if the app is in the background.